# JqGrid setting the last page for datatype local

Tags: jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid which has datatype as local. I am loading data at run time using addRowData, setCell. Every thing is working great. Note that I am not loading the entire data into grid so grid does not know how many pages are there. My server returns the count which I need to set it to the grid. The docs say that lastpage is ReadOnly? How do I set my last page(number of pages) to the grid? Any suggestions. 
Thanks,
Sarath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `addRowData` method to fill jqGrid is the most old and the most ineffective way to fill the data in jqGrid. The problem is easy. If you place an element on the page the position of all other elements on the page have to be recalculated. It makes many resources of the web browser. The filling of the whole jqGrid body in *one step* is much more effectively especially with the large number of inserted rows. It's really needed to use `addRowData` method only in seldom cases.

Much more effective will be to use `data` parameter of jqGrid which allows to fill the grid with the data, sort the data corresponds to `sortname` and `sortorder` and display the first page where `rowNum` defines the number of rows per page. Additionally one should *not* use `afterInsertRow` callback and use `gridview: true`. In the case the filling of jqGrid is the most effective.

The number of pages of the grid will be calculated *automatically* based on the number of rows in the grid. Only if you use *server side* `datatype` (`'json'` or `'xml'`) the client part don't know the total number of pages and so one have to fill in the input data `total`, `page` and `records` together with the main data (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data)). If one uses low level method `addJSONData` one can fill grid with the data and still set `total`, `page` and `records` to any values which you want.

Another way which you can use in some scenarios is `datatype: 'jsonstring'`. The data can be placed as the value of `datastr` option. By the way the value of `datastr` must be not only the JSON string but can be an object too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I started with Json but had to use addRowData and setCell coz my data returned is quite complex json. So will change as suggested on next pass maybe. But currently I am going with custom pager. It would have been convenient though if lastpage was not ReadOnly.

Comment: @Sarath: You are welcome! jqGrid allows to read practically any JSON data. You can either use `jsonReader` or modify JSON data inside of `beforeProcessing` *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid. If you use `jsonReader` with functions (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)) or `jsonmap` which use functions you can read practically any JSON data.